# pg gem install fails on M1 mac: "error: conflicting types for 'PQconnectdb'"

Tags: homebrew, bundler, apple-m1, pg, libpq

I'm installing the `pg` gem on mac osx 12.5 on an M1 macbook pro. Ruby bundler can't find libpq when running `gem install pg`:

```
current directory: /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.4.4/ext
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/ruby -I /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0 extconf.rb
Calling libpq with GVL unlocked
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin/pg_config
checking for whether -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib is accepted as LDFLAGS... yes
Using libpq from /opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*****************************************************************************

Unable to find PostgreSQL client library.

Please install libpq or postgresql client package like so:
  brew install libpq

or try again with:
  gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config

or set library paths manually with:
  gem install pg -- --with-pg-include=/path/to/libpq-fe.h/ --with-pg-lib=/path/to/libpq.so/

...

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-21/3.1.0/pg-1.4.4/mkmf.log
```

Here's what the mkmf.log shows:

```
conftest.c:16:13: error: conflicting types for 'PQconnectdb'
extern void PQconnectdb();
            ^
/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/libpq-fe.h:285:16: note: previous declaration is here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
               ^
conftest.c:17:27: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'conninfo' was not specified
int t(void) { PQconnectdb(); return 0; }
              ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/libpq-fe.h:285:16: note: 'PQconnectdb' declared here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
```

I've installed libpq using homebrew as suggested:

```
Warning: libpq 15.1 is already installed and up-to-date.
```

Interestingly, I also tried `gem install pg -- --with-pg-include=/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include/libpq-fe.h/` but I couldn't find `libpq.so` poking around the homebrew install.

Any suggestions? Is it possible homebrew's installation of libpq leaves off a needed `.so` file? Is it suspect that the log file is under a `x86_64-darwin-21` directory when I'm running on an M1 mac? Is `error: conflicting types for 'PQconnectdb'` a hint that I have an incompatible version of libpq with the pg gem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pg` gem uses `pg_config` to configure itself. If the gem finds the wrong version of `pg_config`, it will misconfigure, resulting in the error you mentioned.

On ARM Macs, Homebrew installs itself to a different location (`/opt/homebrew`) than it did on Intel Macs (`/usr/local`). However, if you used Apple's Migration Assistant, it's possible to end up with both Homebrew instances, which can confuse things when compiling gems.

First, make sure your Ruby is arm64:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 3.1.3p185 (2022-11-24 revision 1a6b16756e) [arm64-darwin22]
```

It should show `arm64` there near the end.

Next, see where pg_config is coming from:

```
$ which pg_config
/usr/local/bin/pg_config      <- Intel version
/opt/homebrew/bin/pg_config   <- ARM version
```

It'll show one of these two (or nothing). We're looking for the second line (ARM).

If nothing, then `postgresql` is probably not installed (or not found).

If it shows the first, then compilation is finding an Intel copy of `pg_config`. This was my case, after migrating from an Intel to ARM Mac.

This confusion is partly made possible because `pg_config` comes from the `postgresql` package, not `libpq`. So, you'll need the arm64 version of `postgresql` installed too.

If you install the unversioned (ie: latest) postgresql, this is hopefully all you need:

```
$ brew install postgresql
```

If you always install a specific version (as I do), then you'll also need to 'link' so that `pg_config` is properly made available.

```
$ brew install postgresql@15
$ brew link postgresql@15
```

Using the link command is usually safe as long as this is the only version of postgresql you have installed (within the ARM copy of Homebrew).

Hint 1: When upgrading versions of Postgres in the future, you may need to unlink the old before linking the new.

Hint 2: If you have an Intel version of Postgres still running from the old copy of Homebrew, there is a possibility you'll have to migrate your data between the two or sort out some other conflict. That's out of scope here, so just a heads up.

At this point you will hopefully see the proper `pg_config`:

```
$ which pg_config
/opt/homebrew/bin/pg_config   <- ARM version
```

If not, also check your `PATH` as set by your shell. It's important that `/opt/homebrew/bin` is before `/usr/local/bin`.

```
$ echo $PATH
```

Fixing it depends on your choice of shell, so I'll skip that here.

That should hopefully do it.

Note that I didn't use `--with-pg-config`. While using that might allow skipping a step or two above, getting `pg_config` detecting properly also helps improve odds that other gems will compile properly in the future and not need ongoing workarounds.

Comment: Late to say thank you, but "Thank you!" My default ruby installed with rbenv was an [x86] version